# Need parent name of Iframe

Tags: asp.net, iframe, parent

I've been searching for a couple hours and haven't found a solution. Hopefully you can help.

I want to get the name & path of the parent page within an Iframe. The reason for this is to prevent the page within the Iframe to be displayed outside it's intended location. If I can get the session variables of the parent page, that would be even better as I could verify the user.

The Iframe will be written in ASP.NET, while the parent page is PHP.

I have found Javascript code that might work, but I'm very unfamiliar with javascript and how to pass the return value to the code behind in ASP.NET. If your solution involves javascript, I will need the whole thing from calling it in the form load to getting back the value.

I have tried these functions, but they don't show what I need.

```
Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString
Request.ApplicationPath.ToString
Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath.ToString
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you looking for a code behind solution and redirect, but the code behind can not recognize if the page is calling from some other.

You may try the `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]` but this can make mistake, and can even been disable by some users, or changed.

One simple working solution with javascript is to check on the iframe it self if its inside your master page or not. So this code go to the page that lives inside the iframe, and if see that is alone is redirect the user back to the master page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    // this line is check if its inside an iframe.
    // if top==self then is not in iframe
    if(top == self)
    {
        alert("This page can not be viewed alone, please press ok to load the master page");
        top.location.replace("MasterPage.aspx");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I hear what you're saying, I think, about checking from the parent page, but in this case, the parent is PHP, not ASP.NET. And even if that would work from PHP, that still wouldn't prevent someone from opening the ASP.net page outside the Iframe.

Comment: @TomCollins The `ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]` exist on PHP too (probably with some other name), also the javascript runs on browser. make a test only with this javascript and you see the effect and how is work. Is simple.

Comment: It only lists itself, and not the parent page.

Comment: OK, that tests if it's in an Iframe, which is good (and works). But security sake, I'd still like to see the name of the parent. I tried top.name & window.parent.name, but both of those say "undefined". So close.

Comment: @TomCollins Try the `document.location`

Comment: That didn't give me the parent name, but I got to thinking that the parent name can be easily forged as well. It did give me the server name so I think that will be secure enough. Thanks for your help!!